# How to change contents of <p> based off select option

Tags: javascript, html

I've read many topics on this and nothing is working. I'm trying to do something really simple, but cant seem to get it to work. I'm trying to have the elements of a drop down box change the values in my paragraph text. Here is the script I'm running:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function fn(){
    var x = document.getElementById("DescChange");
    var y = document.getElementById("CostChange");
    var a = document.getElementById("dropdown");

    a.addEventListener('change', function(){
        if (a.value == 0){
            x.innerHTML = "Description: Basic care for car including wax and buffer";
            y.innerHTML = "Total cost:" + 59.99;
        }
        else if (a.value == 1){
            x.innerHTML = "Mid-level care for car including Basic services and repainting";
            y.innerHTML = "Total cost:" + 119.99;
        }
        else if (a.value == 2){
            x.innerHTML = "Advanced care for car including Basic, Intermediate and interior + window repair";
            y.innerHTML = "Total cost:" + 299.99;
        }
        else{
            x.innerHTML = "";
            y.innerHTML = "";
        }

      });

    }
</script>
```

And here is my div with the select options:

```
<div>
    <h2><u>Products and Services</u></h2>
    <h4>
        <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="empty"></option>
    <option value="0">Basic</option> 
    <option value="1">Intermediate</option> 
    <option value="2">Advanced</option> 
        </select>

    <p id="DescChange">1</p>
    <p id="CostChange">2</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    </h4>
</div>
```

I'm not getting any errors in my browser console. I feel like its something really easy that I'm missing, but I can't figure it out. I appreciate any help!

EDIT 1: I updated my script based off an answer below. Currently 1 `<p>` is updating: The advanced tag.... trying to find the discrepancies.

Edit 2: its working. I messed up on if/else if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to listen for the [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) event of the dropdown, otherwise your code will run only once when the page is loaded.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function fn(){
        var x = document.getElementById("DescChange");
        var y = document.getElementById("CostChange");
        var a = document.getElementById("dropdown");  // <-- removed ".value"

        a.addEventListener('change', function() {    // <-- added event handler
            if (a.value == 0){
                x.innerHTML = "Description: Basic care for car including wax and buffer";
                y.innerHTML = "Total cost:" + 59.99;
            }
            else{
                x.innerHTML = "";
                y.innerHTML = "";
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The anonymous function that wraps the code is called [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers). It is called whenever the value of the dropdown changes.

Comment: I'm now getting an error in the browser console: `a.addEventListener is not a function
    at fn`. EDIT: I missed the removed `.value`. I removed it I am currently not getting an error, but nothing is still displaying in the `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

for me **snwflk** code is fine
I only think using think simpler code,
with better variable name,
and not using innerHTML when it is not necessary => use **textContent**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let
    DescChange = document.getElementById("Desc-Change"),
    CostChange = document.getElementById("Cost-Change"),
    mySelect   = document.getElementById("dropdown")
  ;


  mySelect.onchange = function(){

    switch (mySelect.value)  {
      case '0':
        DescChange.textContent = "Description: Basic care for car including wax and buffer";
        CostChange.textContent = "Total cost: " + 59.99;
      break;
      case '1':
        DescChange.textContent = "Mid-level care for car including Basic services and repainting"
        CostChange.textContent = "Total cost: " + 119.99;
      break;
      case '2':
        DescChange.textContent = "Advanced care for car including Basic, Intermediate and interior + window repair";
        CostChange.textContent = "Total cost: " + 299.99;
      break;
      default:
        DescChange.textContent = "";
        CostChange.textContent = "";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2><u>Products and Services</u></h2>
  <h4>
    <select id="dropdown">
      <option value="empty" disabled selected> please select </option>
      <option value="0">Basic</option>
      <option value="1">Intermediate</option>
      <option value="2">Advanced</option>
    </select>

    <p id="Desc-Change">1</p>
    <p id="Cost-Change">2</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </h4>
</div>
```